# Update ONLY some fields of attached Entity

Tags: entity-framework

I'm using .NET 3.5 SP1. I have entity 'AppUser':

```
public class AppUser : System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityObject{   
 public int Uid {get; set;}   
 public string UserName {get; set;}   
 public string Password {get; set;}   
 public DateTime LastLogin {get; set;}   
 public string Name {get; set;}   
 public string Address {get; set;}
 public string Comment {get; set;} 
 ...........   
}
```

To update ALL fields of an attached enitity:

```
   public void Update(AppUser updateUser) {
    AppUser user = ctx.AppUserSet.Where(u => u.UserId == userId).FirstOrDefault();
    //This will update ALL fields
    ctx.ApplyPropertyChanges(user.EntityKey.EntitySetName, updateUser);
    ctx.SaveChanges();   
    }
```

I want to update all fields except Password and LastLogin. I can update individual fields, but will be cumbersome for entities with large number of fields.

Please tell, what is the best way to achive this?

Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

Change the setters for those two properties to private in the EDMX/model.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you can do this directly with EF without extra programming effort.

There are three possibilities:

- Update through a view
- Update using a stored procedure
- Change your data model, such that the password and lastlogin are in a seperate table with a one to one relationship.

All of these require extra programming effort.